# Unable to install Ghostscript 9.50 with base image as Ubuntu 16.04 using dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, upgrade

Currently my container is up with Ghostscript 9.26 and it has Ubuntu 16.04 as the base image. I want to install the latest gs version 9.50 without changing my existing docker Ubuntu(16.04) image. 
I want to know the changes I need to make in my Dockerfile to get the latest gs version

Comment: If Ghostscript 9.26 works then Ghostscript 9.50 should work. As far as I can see, you just need to install Ghostscript. I know nothing about docker, I can't see that this is a Ghostscript question.

Comment: Your title says 'unable to install Ghostscript' but you haven't said what you mean by that, what errors do you get when you try ?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help to add ghostscript on docker:

https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases